# Excessive typing for class-based React component

Tags: flowtype

Flow version: 0.186.0

There's simple React component

```js
//@flow
import * as React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component<{}> {
    onClick = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        console.log(event);
    };

    render(): React.Node {
        return <button onClick={this.onClick}>test</button>
    }
}
```

I'm using property syntax for `onClick` to avoid applying `.bind(this)` every time

Since I export component, flow throws an error

```
Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type
annotation at property `onClick`: [signature-verification-failure]
```

I'm aware of type-first mode which may want addition export types:

```js
    onClick: ((event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void) = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        console.log(event);
    };
```

Question - Is this the only right way to fix this error? Isn't this way too verbose?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `onClick` method is public so it needs to be explicitely typed.

You can make Flow understand that it's a "private" method (even if it's not really) but adding a `_` prefix:

```
_onClick = (event: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        console.log(event);
    };
```